# How to get Telegram Bot Super Group ID?

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

How to get Telegram Bot Super Group ID?

With This Code:

```
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log(msg);
});
```

I Can See my Private Channel ID in `forward_from_chat: { id: -1001125265425`, of the object, That is Okey.
**But How Can I Get Super Group ID?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should add a bot to that group.

Then if the group is **public** (has `@username`), just send message to the group and read reply from Telegram server, it will be of type [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message), and Message->Chat->Id is group's ID.

If the group is **private** (doesn't have a `@username`), then you can mention a bot in your message and, again, read reply from Telegram server.

Or you can use some third-party bots, for example, [@my_id_bot](https://t.me/my_id_bot), which I made specifically for this.

Comment: @my_id_bot did the trick for me, just add it and send a message like  /getid. thks

Comment: Hey, @rodrigorf, I'm that bot's creator and for supergroups you can just add the bot to the group to get its ID. Did you have to ping him explicitly?

Comment: Hey @Groosha, that's exactly what i did. I added the bot to the group, but i had to run the command /geid@myidbot to show the number

Comment: ops, my mistake, i have run: /getgroupid@myidbot